# "Script could not be translated from: null" error returned

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Here is the code in pinescript:

```
'//@version=2'
// Lookback period for calculating the Moving Average
length = input(20, minval=1)

// Breakout level
breakout = input(2)

// Moving Average
sma = sma(close, length)

// Calculate the distance between the current price and the Moving Average
distance = abs(close - sma)

// Check if the distance is greater than the breakout level
if (distance > breakout)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("Close Long", "Long", stop=sma)


if (distance > breakout) and (close > sma)

if (distance < breakout) or (close < sma)
    strategy.close("Long")

takeProfit = input(5)
strategy.exit("Take Profit", "Long", limit=sma + takeProfit)

stopLoss = input(3)
strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "Long", stop=sma - stopLoss)
```

When I try to run it on tradingview, I get the error "Script could not be translated from: null" I am entirely new, so I dont know how to fix this. What should I change?

I tried changing and adding different lines, but nothing has worked so far. Again, I am super new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script must have one `study()` or `strategy()` call. In your case it is `strategy()`.

Add `strategy("test")` to your script and it will work.

Note: You have one empty if statement so you should remove that too if you are not using it.